# Search column on other sheet for similar value

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets that has 2 columns on Sheet1 and 1 column on Sheet2.

```
Sheet1
ColA, ColB
First Name, Target ColB for update
Last Name, ...

Sheet2
ColA
firstname
lastname
```

I'd like to Update column B on sheet1 if it finds similar value in sheet2.
For example:

```
First Name, firstname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're going to need the [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011)

Used properly, it should allow you to find approximate matches such as `McIntosh` and `MacIntosh` or `Sara` and `Sarah`.

Edit:
N.B. Using this add-in will make your document less portable. Anyone you send it to will also need to have that Add-In installed. This should only be considered an option if a small number of people will need to use this file, and they can all install the Add-In.